# Languages and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have a problem with this multi-language script.  You can look at the script code [here](http://web-tourist.net/login/login/view.php?st=3460)

I'm trying to reuse this script as follows:

```
<?
                     $query = " SELECT * FROM `filmi` order by id desc " . " LIMIT 5" ;
                     $result = @mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');


                  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                   echo "
 <div class=\"slide\">
        <a href=\"property.php?id=$row[id]\" target=\"_self\">
        <div class=\"caption\"><p>" . getLanguageText('menu.zaglavie') . " - $row[rezume] beds, $row[rejis] baths:  <span class=\"price\">" . number_format($row['seriq']) . " €</span></p></div></div>
           ";
           }
                ?>
```

When I make the change `getLanguageText('menu.zaglavie') = $row[BG] or $row[DE]`, it displays text only and not the content in `$row`.

How do I display the content for each `$row`?

Comment: Please, don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` extension anymore. It's _deprecated_, _expired_, _it rests in peace_, _it's pushing up the daisies_. Use `PDO`  or `mysqli_` instead. Also: be clear, because _"getLanguageText('menu.zaglavie') = $row[BG] or $row[DE]"_ just makes no sense... what are you trying to do? what have you tried? add code examples

Comment: no with this " . getLanguageText('menu.zaglavie') . "  i try to get $row[languageEN] or $row[languageDE] content.

Comment: The `getLanguageText` function can't access the `$row` array, because you're not passing it to the function. If that function returns `EN` or `DE`, you could do something like `$key = 'language'.getLanguageText()`, and then get `$row[$key]`. But that would imply your table has several fields, one for each language... that's just a bad idea: adding a language would mean altering your table, and that might mean a tbl rebuild + `SELECT *` implies your fetching _all_ language strings, including those you don't need.

Comment: So what will be the most easiest way , with changing the language to change and table. i all ready create new table's in database. TitleEN for english and TitleDE for german but , how to get the content from those table's.

Comment: The easiest way to go about this, is to _not_ reinvent the wheel. Translators have been made, and [are available free to download and use](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Translation.html). You can use XML files for translations, tables... it's your choice, really